# Multiply exponent with its modular inverse in Java

Tags: java, math

I try to implement the zero knowledge proof of set membership from the paper https://content.sciendo.com/downloadpdf/journals/popets/2015/2/article-p25.pdf (the protocol defined in figure 4). 
The protocol uses values of the form `y = g^(1/x)` (I have simplified the form for this post). The protocol relies on the fact `y^x = g`. This all seems very reasonable. However, these operations are done in a multiplicative group of order `p` where `g` is the generator of that group. So `1/x` is equal to the modular inverse of `x`. But if you now perform the computation of `y^x` again, this will not result in `g`. 
One small example. Assume we have `p = 11`, `g = 2` and `x = 2`. Now we get `y = 2^(1/2) mod 11`. The inverse of 2 modulo 11 is 6 so `y = 2^6 mod 11 = 9 mod 11`. Now raising `y` to the power of `x` (`9^2`), gives `81 mod 11 = 4 mod 11` which is not equal to `g`. This is due to the fact the inverse of `x` and `x` do not cancel each other out. In order to get `g` you expect `y^x mod 11 = (2^6)^2 mod 11 = 2^(6*2) mod 11 = 2^1 mod 11 = g`. However this is mathematically not correct. 
So how else can I implement this part of the protocol?
What I have so far (note that I use BigInteger since that is what the protocol needs eventually):

```
public class Setmembership {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger x = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
        BigInteger g = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
        BigInteger p = BigInteger.valueOf(11);
        BigInteger y = g.modPow(x.modInverse(p), p);
        System.out.println(y.modPow(x, p) + "should be equal to " + g);
    }
}
```

I hope the problem is clear. If not please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: Please show us the code you have.

Comment: Not clear. Are you asking how to calculate the multiplicative modular inverse in some base in Java? The formula I know (and which seems to work) is `minv(n, p) = minv(p % n, p) * (p - p / n) % p` (plus some checks for n <= 1 and n > p). Can you show a reference for your approach?

Comment: @KunLun I have the following line `BigInteger.valueOf(2).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(6).modInverse(BigInteger.valueOf(11)), BigInteger.valueOf(11)).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(6), BigInteger.valueOf(11))`. I use BigIntegers since the protocol will have to use these.

Comment: Please use the function `Edit` and put the code in your question.

Comment: @tobias_k No I know how to compute the inverse. Sorry I find it hard to make it clearer. Normally if you do `a * a^(-1) mod p` it results in 1, but now I want achieve this in the exponent. I first compute `b^(a^(-1))` and later on I want to raise this to the power `a` so that it results in `b`. For a number example see the main post. I hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: @tobias_k First I compute `y = g^(1/x) mod p` and later on in the protocol I compute `y^x mod p`. This last must give 1 as a result. So in "normal" arithmetics an example is `(2^(1/2))^2 = 2`

Comment: Okay, final question: _should_ this actually work with the multiplicative inverse? I mean, in `(a^(1/b))^b`, you never actually multiply anything _by_ `b` or `b^-1`...

Comment: Yeah so `(a^(1/b))^b = a^((1/b)*b) = a^(b^(-1)*b)`, but I do not know if `b` and the inverse of `b` in the exponent can cancel each other out to 1. This is what the protocol does so therefore I assume it should be possible

Comment: Hm, but that means you apply modulo arithmetics to the exponent, which does not seem legal, e.g. `2^13 % 11 != 2^(13 % 11) % 11`, so I guess your premise is wrong.

Comment: That is indeed true. Do you know how I can then implement this part of the protocol? So how to compute `y = g^(1/x)` and then satisfying `y^x = g` in a multiplicative group? I try to implement the protocol in figure 4 from https://content.sciendo.com/downloadpdf/journals/popets/2015/2/article-p25.pdf Thanks for the effort so far!

Comment: Glad we've got that sorted out. I don't think I can help you, though. You should start by thoroughly rewording your question, add the examples and a link to that paper, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mre]. This means that the code needs to be runnable. In java this means it needs to be in a class, have a public static void main method, and the necessary import statements. This way we can put it into our ide and debug it for you.

Comment: I don't think you are operating in the correct group. You are operating in (Z_p)*, but that group has order p-1. I'm not familiar with zero knowledge but I believe the groups in question are usually elliptic curve groups.